# android ImageView: Place image on top

Tags: android

I have an activity containing only one `ImageView`. This view should display an image loaded from an URL. I want, that this image will be shown on the top of my screen using the whole screen width.
My layout-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/overview_bgColor" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/overview_image"
            android:contentDescription="image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|fill_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But the image is always shown vertically centered. But why? I thought, that `top` will place this `ImageView` on top of my screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/overview_bgColor" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/overview_image"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"            
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this works, thanks a lot. But why doesn't `top` place the image view on top of the screen?

Comment: it actually did place it on top, but the view bounds were not set to leave the correct ratio. you can verify though, leave your old code, and add a background to the imageview and see what happens, you'll see a big image with the background color on top and bottom

Comment: so the exact way would be to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to my code or does `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` implicit place the `ImageView` on top?

Comment: the adjustViewBounds will literally calculate the width of the image you set to match_parent, and then calculate its height to keep the ratio, otherwise it will mess things up, and anyway you have to be carefull with imageviews in android, and IT WILL NOT PLACE IT ON TOP